# How to add a plugin in angularjs project

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova, plugins, visual-studio-2013

I want to use the Cordova facebook plugin for my project. Since the instructions are done for phonegap I get confused when I have to use it only on angular.

So here is what I have so far.

1.I add the CordovaFacebook.js in my scripts and reference it in bundleConfig.
2.I create a new service.js file like this:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app.FacebookService', []); // extend the app

var plugin = new CC.CordovaFacebook();

app.factory('FacebookService', [ 'plugin', function(plugin) {

plugin.init('1111111111', 'Cordova',
    ['public_profile', 'email', 'publish_actions'],
    function(response) {
        if (response) {
            console.log("Access token is: " + response.accessToken);
            console.log("Expires: " + response.expirationDate);
            console.log("Permissions are: " + response.permissions);
        }
    }, failureCallback);


    plugin.login(function(response) {
        console.log("Access token is: " + response.accessToken);
        console.log("Expires: " + response.expirationDate);
        console.log("Permissions are: " + response.permissions);
    }, failureCallback);

}]);
```

1. I add this app.service in the App.js file
2. And at this point I am stuck, when I run my application it says  `CC` from `CC.CordovaFacebook()` is not defined.

Can you please let me know how is this done step by step. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this was. Load all the cordova files on your root. And reference them. 
In that way the module.exports = CC; will be defined.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your reference to bundleConfig does not contain CordovaFacebook.js, so your code complaining about CC namespace defined in CordovaFacebook.js.

If you are using Cordova, why don't you simply try `cordova plugin add ...` from command line to use the plugin? I am pretty sure it's a cordova plugin (hint: I wrote this plugin).

Comment: I realized I made a mistake when I reference it . But now it complains about    uncaught reference module.exports = CC;

Comment: @Aseb: Yes, I am the author of the plugin. I really suggest using cordova cli call to install the plugin. CC is used only for one purpose, not to clutter global namespace. An exception means you have a linkage issue, which I hope would be solved by cordova cli use.

Comment: How to install it through  visual studio ??

Comment: @Aseb: cli is installed with cordova and node.js, even if you use vs, you can use command prompt to use cordova cli calls. Not that hard, just need some getting used to.

Comment: I actually got all the cordova files and added in my solution and not its OK. At least my project starts. 
I have a controller like this :

    FacebookController.$inject = ['$scope', 'CordovaFacebook'];
    function FacebookController($scope, CordovaFacebook) {

        var plugin = new CC.CordovaFacebook();

But plugin its undefined now . 
Where do you suggest me to add the files , on app.js and the controllers ?

Comment: I would inject the plugin to my angularjs controller, which you seem like did it somehow. Problem of undefined is related to your (not) referencing js file properly from the calling js.